# Java – multiple call on DAO causes exception (wildly, jboss)

Tags: java, rest, jboss, dao, wildfly-8

I am building a java REST application. Therefor I am using jboss on a wildfly 8 server.

The following code causes this exception: `JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)`

```
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
public class UsersEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(User user) {

        try {
            this.checkUsername(user.getUsername());
            this.checkEmail(user.getEmail());
            return Response.ok(userDAO.create(user)).build();;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                           .entity(e.getMessage())
                           .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                           .entity(e.getMessage())
                           .build();
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("username")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response username(String username) {

        try {
            this.checkUsername(username);
            return Response.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                           .entity(entity)
                           .build();
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("email")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response email(String email) {
        try {
            this.checkEmail(email);
            return Response.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                           .entity(this.validator.validateError(null, e))
                           .build();
        }
    }

    private void checkUsername(String username) throws IOException {
        try {
            userDAO.get(username);
            throw new IOException("Username is taken allready.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) { throw e; }
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Username can be used"); }
    }

    private void checkEmail(String email) throws IOException {
        try {
            userDAO.getByEmail(email);
            throw new IOException("Email is taken allready.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) { throw e; }
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Email can be used"); }
    }
}
```

The `public Response email(String email)` and `public Response username(String username)` functions are working fine. The Problem seems to be the call of both functions through the `public Response create(User user)` function:

```
...
try {
    this.checkUsername(user.getUsername());
    this.checkEmail(user.getEmail());
    ...
```

So now when I have a correct username but a duplicate email the exception `JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)` is going to be thrown in the `userDAO.getByEmail(email)`. When I have a duplicate username instead the `IOException("Username is taken allready.")` is going to be thrown as expected.

When I change the order of those functions to:

```
...
try {
    this.checkEmail(user.getEmail());
    this.checkUsername(user.getUsername());
    ...
```

the same problem occurs but in `userDAO.get(username)` and with a correct email and a duplicate username.

**EDIT**

When I am removing `throw new IOException("Username is taken allready.");` in `private void checkUsername(String username) throws IOException { }` the second DAO call is working fine. So the problem seems to be the Exception that is thrown. How can I solve that?

My UserDAO

```
public interface UserDAO {
    public User create(User user) throws Exception;
    public User get(String username) throws Exception;
    public User getByEmail(String email) throws Exception;
}
```

My UserBean

```
@Stateless
@Remote(UserDAO.class)
public class UserBean implements UserDAO {

    // Injected database connection:
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) throws Exception {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public User get(String username) throws Exception {
        return em.createNamedQuery(User.QUERY_USERNAME, User.class)
                 .setParameter("userName", username)
                 .getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public User getByEmail(String email) throws Exception {
        return em.createNamedQuery(User.QUERY_EMAIL, User.class)
                 .setParameter("email", email)
                 .getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is poorly designed code. You should refactor it to make it more clear and consistent. Also post your DAO layer code if you're experiencing a problem with it.

Comment: @Justas Thank you. Can you please go more in detail when you say poorly designed code?

Comment: Why do throw exceptions to identify boolean expressions? Did you read/try this or other SO solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300014/object-is-not-getting-persisted-using-jpa-jta-jboss-cdi?